# File was not quarantined properly when trying to install chromedriver using brew

Tags: python, macos, selenium-chromedriver, homebrew

I have already tried to install via `brew cask install chromedriver` but I get this error:

```
Error: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/42621d77ecaa889fa8ca73ac4b2a2228e3c1d11f20d84c6898e7645397d00f1d--chromedriver_mac64.zip was not quarantined properly.
```

How do I fix this error? I am using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.5

Comment: Have the same exact problem while installing any packages from cask.

Comment: Have you tried removing the file?

Comment: I see the same issue on macOS 10.15.7. `brew install adoptopenjdk11` gives `Error: adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk11: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/46eb376eab731542b0487be7fb6281dd11b32cf1ef7f5d8b0e092c99416c66b0--OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_11.0.9.1_1.pkg was not quarantined properly.`

Comment: I have fixed this, but I'm not sure what actually solved it. It might have been `sudo diskutil resetUserPermissions / \`id -u\``.